# How can I parse specific text from a string?

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have this string array:

```
     private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
    "http://192.168.1.18:8098/?cmd=nothing",
    "http://192.168.1.16:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
```

What I want is to end up with the following:

```
"http://192.168.1.18:8098/?cmd="
```

This is how I'm currently getting that value:

```
iptouse = ipaddresses[i].Substring(0, 26);
```

The problem is that `Substring(0, 26)` was working if the string was, for example:

http://10.0.0.5:8098/?cmd=nothing

How can I parse until the end of "cmd=" in all cases?

Comment: If input would be Uri you'd use `Uri` class and `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString` to extract data. Since you don't specify what values are stored in your array and it is not clear what "parse until the cmd=" actually means it is hard to provide good answer.

Comment: @Nighthawk441 - probably should be dup of one of "get query string from Uri", but it is not clear to me what exactly OP is looking for and what other variations of input strings are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the same output I would do this

```
string ipaddress = ipaddresses[i].Substring(0,ipaddresses[i].LastIndexOf("=")+1);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking into the [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) method. Here's an example:

```
string ip = "http://192.168.1.18:8098/?cmd=nothing".Split('=')[0] + "=";
Console.WriteLine(ip); // "http://192.168.1.18:8098/?cmd="
```

This will split on "=", return everything before the "=", and then append "=" to the end of it.

In your case, it would be the following:

```
iptouse = ipaddresses[i].Split('=')[0] + "=";
```

This answer assumes `cmd` will always be the first query parameter, but assuming your provided format is always the case, it will work just fine.